botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId exception handling
When using Boto3, is there a way to implement exception for "InvalidInstanceId"? Specifically: "botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId"
There is exception handling for "ClientError" and other errors. For example by adding: "from botocore.exceptions import ClientError".
Root causes for "InvalidInstanceId" are listed without the exception handling part, so our program crashes whenever there is an issue with calling "ssm_client.send_command".
InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html

From the documentation, you can catch InvalidInstanceId by catching SSM.Client.exceptions.InvalidInstanceId class
try:
  response = ssm_client.send_command( InstanceIds=[instanceid], ...)
except ssm_client.exceptions.InvalidInstanceId as ex:
  print(ex.response)


Thanks very much. That solved the issue. Previously, I tried "except (ClientError, InvalidInstanceId) as e:", which did not work. Then based on your example, I tried "except ssm_client.exceptions.InvalidInstanceId as e:", which did work.
